# How to use Automapper to map controller methods to viewmodel properties for a asp.net mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am trying to leverage the Automapper for mapping the controller methods to the viewmodel properties in an asp.net mvc project.
I analyzed few articles about Automapper and found that it is wonderful object to object mapper between complex model object and viewmodel object.
I have code in a controller: CustomersController.cs

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var user = _userService.GetUser(_profile.UserName);
            if (!user.IsActive)
                return RedirectToAction("");

            var clientGroups = new List<ClientGroup>();                 

            var model = new CustomerGroupsIndexViewModel()
            {

                CustomerGroupUsersUrl = Url.RouteUrl<CustomerGroupsController>(c => c.GetUsersForCustomerGroup(null, null, null, 0, 0)),
                CustomerGroupByAreaUrl = Url.RouteUrl<CustomerGroupsController >(c => c.GetAreaDetailsForCustomerGroup(null, null, null, 0, 0)),

                CheckLoginNameUrl = Url.RouteUrl<UsersController>(c => c.CheckLoginName(null)),
                ResetUserUrl = Url.RouteUrl<UsersController>(c => c.ResetPassword(null)),
                GetSelectOptionsForCustomerGroupUrl = Url.RouteUrl<ClientGroupsController>(c => c.GetSelectOptionsForCustomerGroup(null,null)),

                FindUsersMatchingTermUrl = Url.RouteUrl<UsersController>(c => c.FindUsersMatchingWithLoginName(null)),
                NumberOfTestTaken = _scanService.GetCustomerForUser(user).Count(),                
                RefreshCustomerGroupUrl = Url.RouteUrl<CustomerGroupsController >(c => c.RefreshClientGroup()),
            };

            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

            return View("CustomerGroupIndex", model);
        }
```

I have such methods across the project code base. 
Can anyone help me how can I use Automapper efficiently here?

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 2):

I 'll explain it very briefly

Create configuration for each Model and related ViewModel like this

Interface for configuration:

```
interface IGlobalConfiguration
    {
        void Configure();
    }
```

Class for configuration:

```
public class AutoMapperViewModelConfiguration : IGlobalConfiguration
    {
        public void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Model1,ViewModel1>();

            Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel1,Model1>()
        .ForMember(x => x.ModelMember1, y => y.Ignore());//Ignore if not required
        }
    }
```

Create a class and method like this:

```
public class GlobalConfigurationModule
    {
        private readonly Assembly assembly;

        public GlobalConfigurationModule()
            : this(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        {
        }

        public GlobalConfigurationModule(Assembly assembly)
        {
            this.assembly = assembly;
        }

        public void Load()
        {
            var ins = from x in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                      where x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IGlobalConfiguration))
                      select Activator.CreateInstance(x) as IGlobalConfiguration;

            foreach (var config in ins)
            {
                config.Configure();
            }
        }
    }
```

Call the Load method in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {

            new GlobalConfigurationModule().Load();
}
```

When you require to map a Model to ViewModel use this Mapper.Map() method like this:

```
Mapper.Map(model1Object, viewModel1Object);
```

**Edit:**

If you need the mapping should be done from a method you can create mapping like this.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.SomeValue, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetSomeValue()))
```

You cannot map a method returns void.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply Prasanth. Here you have created the mapping between Model and ViewModel. Can you please help me by showing a code sample showing the mapping between the controller methods and the viewmode?

Comment: Can you please give me a clear idea about your requirement? I have given you the sample code. It clearly shows how to map between different models. If you need to map using automapper you can add a configuration in the configuration file.

Comment: I have some methods within the controller class:CustomerController.cs which I need to map to the viewmodel properties. I have drafted the code sample in the question section above.Can you please help how I can use Automapper in this case?

Comment: If you need to map from a method you have to use mapping as above (please see edited section).